# How can i import RSACryptoServiceProvider private key to bouncy castle

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, rsacryptoserviceprovider

Currently, I am using the etoken (safenet), bouncy castle library and X509certificate2 to decrypt a p7m file.

I would like to decrypt the p7m byteArray through the Bouncy Castle library using a X509Ceritificate2 private key. I can retrieve the X509Ceritificate2 private key from the X509Store and the key is not null. I can utilize the private key when it is a RSACryptoServiceProvider object.

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider systemUserOnlyReadablePrivateKey = certificate.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
```

However, when I tried to tranform the private key from RSACryptoServiceProvider object to other objects such as byte[] or AsymetricKeyParameter, An exception message "key not valid for use in specified state." has been shown.

```
AsymetricKeyParameter key = DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(cert.Privat‌​eKey).Private; //Exception prompt
```

Since the certificates are stored in the eToken and automatically added in the X509Store when eToken plugin into computer and certificates removed when the eToken plugged out, I can not set the certificates as exportable.

1. Does Bouncy Castle API support decryption by using X509Ceritificate2 private key?
2. How can I transform the key into other object so that I can decrypt by the Bouncy Castle API.

Thanks.

The following is my source code.

```
byte[] p7mByte = p7mByteArray; //p7m to byte array

cmsEnvelopedData = new CmsEnvelopedDataParser(p7mByteArray);
RecipientInformationStore recipientInformationStore = cmsEnvelopedData.GetRecipientInfos();

RecipientInformation recipientInformation = null;

X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);
var certificates = store.Certificates;

foreach (var certificate in certificates)
{
  if (certificate.PrivateKey != null)
  {
     RecipientID recipientId = new RecipientID();
     recipientId.SerialNumber = certificate.SerialNumber;
     recipientId.Issuer = certificate.IssuerDN;
     recipientInformation = recipientInformationStore.GetFirstRecipient(recipientId);

     RSACryptoServiceProvider systemUserOnlyReadablePrivateKey = certificate.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
     CspParameters cspParameters = new CspParameters(systemUserOnlyReadablePrivateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderType, systemUserOnlyReadablePrivateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderName, systemUserOnlyReadablePrivateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName)
     {
        Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseArchivableKey 
     };

     RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParameters);
     csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PrivateKey;

     CmsTypedStream recData = null;
     recData = recipientInformation.GetContentStream(DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(cert.Privat‌​eKey).Private); //Exception prompt
  }
}
```

Comment: Finally, I have used the System.Security.Cryptography instead of Bouncy Castle for decryption. The envelopedCms.Decrypt() function will automatically load the corresponding private key for the decryption. So I dont need to export the private key and put it into Bouncy Castle API. EnvelopedCms envelopedCms = new EnvelopedCms(); envelopedCms.Decode(p7mByteArray); envelopedCms.Decrypt();

Comment: For bouncy castle to get your key, the certificate installed in the store should have the parameter `Exportable` set to true. if it is not, the underlying API that gets used prevents this kind of access.